# How can I update a Label while I save something in CoreData?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, core-data

I want to download data from Firebase Database and save it into CoreData. Because this takes a few seconds I want to present the user a label that shows how many words were saved. But in my App, it always started but the label didn’t get updated. Is it because the saving process und UI change are both on the main thread?

Download of the words:

```
var entityName = "Words"
var level = "Beginner"

Database.database().reference().child("Words").child(level).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
        let word = Word(original: "\(dict["original"]!)", translated: "\(dict["translated"]!)", level: "\(dict["level"]!)", phase: "1", lastQuery: dateFormatter.string(from: date), learned: false)
        allWords.append(word)
        self.saveWord(entity: entityName, word: word)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.label.text = "\(allWords.count)"
    }
}
```

Saving:

```
func saveWord(entity: String, word: Word) {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entityName = entity

    guard let newEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: context) else {
        return
    }

    let newWord = NSManagedObject(entity: newEntity, insertInto: context)

    let original = word.original
    let translated = word.translated
    let level = word.level
    let phase = "1"
    let lastQuery = word.lastQuery
    let learned = false

    newWord.setValue(original, forKey: "original")
    newWord.setValue(translated, forKey: "translated")
    newWord.setValue(level, forKey: "level")
    newWord.setValue(phase, forKey: "phase")
    newWord.setValue(lastQuery, forKey: "lastQuery")
    newWord.setValue(learned, forKey: "learned")

    do {
        try context.save()
        print("Saved: \(original)")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: This `DispatchQueue.main.async` is not needed for this use case as UI calls within Firebase closures are run on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix... change the code to this so if a child is skipped you're not needlessly refreshing the count. Also, Firebase UI calls are run on the main thread so the DispatchQueue is not needed and will in fact result in only the total count being displayed.

```
var entityName = "Words"
var level = "Beginner"

Database.database().reference().child("Words").child(level).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
        let word = Word(original: "\(dict["original"]!)", translated: "\(dict["translated"]!)", level: "\(dict["level"]!)", phase: "1", lastQuery: dateFormatter.string(from: date), learned: false)
        allWords.append(word)
        self.saveWord(entity: entityName, word: word)
        self.label.text = "\(allWords.count)"
    }
}
```

Keep in mind though, Firebase is very fast. If the node you're reading from has several thousand children, you really won't see the counter incrementing in the UI, it will have iterated over all of those children is less than a second and you're UI will show 0... and then the total child count.

Comment: But is there a way I can show the number? Because I have exactly the scenario you described.

Comment: @max Which number? As I mentioned, even with a couple thousand documents, it will iterate over them so quickly - literally in the blink of an eye - there would be no point in trying to show it increment in the UI as it would only take a fraction of a second. But if you have considerably more than that 10,000 for example, the code in my answer works and will update the 'count' in the label as they are loading in.